# obtener valor url javascript

Tags: javascript

Buenas Quisiera que me puedan ayudar estoy queriendo realizando una validación en javascript lo siguiente.
Les explico estoy realizando es que tengo datos de una tabla donde hay un campo llamado Estado. y cuando el estado esta en  **proceso** cuando le presionen en ver quiero que si en estado dice procesado salga un mensaje que o un alert esta en proceso . Si me podrian ayudar porfavor

ESTA ES LA TABLA QUE TIENEN DATOS.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por que ahora cuando le dan en ver se direcciona a otra pagina pero como podria hacer que cuando este en estado en **PROCESO** NO SE REDIRECCIONE Y SALGA ESE MENSAJE .

**Script**

```
<script>
      function getQueryVariable(variable) {
          console.log(variable);
          var proceso = variable;
          if(proceso=="3")
          {
              alert("prueba");
              return true;
          }

      }
  </script>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

le puse un console.log pero en la variable que extrae extrae el numero 5 y no entiendo porque porque debe agarra el numero 3 ya que en url idestadoincidencia dice 3 .

Comment: Podrías editar tu pregunta e ingresar el código que usas para llenar ese `DataTables`

Comment: @Davlio no es un Datatable es una tabla <table> lo que queria realizar es capturar el valor de el enlace: IdIncidencia  en un javascript

<a href=DetalleSolucionIncidenciaUsuario.aspx?opt=1&IdIncidencia=1 onclick="getQueryVariable(3)">ver

ya que queria realizar que valide que si esa variable que capture es 1 salga un mensaje y no se redireccione. y si es otro que se direccione

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías agregar el `return`:

```
<a href=DetalleSolucionIncidenciaUsuario.aspx?opt=1&IdIncidenci‌​a=1 onclick="return getQueryVariable(3)">Ver</a>
```

```js
function getQueryVariable(variable) {
    console.log(variable);
    var proceso = variable;
    if(proceso=="3")
    {
        alert("prueba");
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<a href=DetalleSolucionIncidenciaUsuario.aspx?opt=1&IdIncidenci‌​a=1 onclick="return getQueryVariable(3)">Ver Valor 3</a>
<a href=DetalleSolucionIncidenciaUsuario.aspx?opt=1&IdIncidenci‌​a=1 onclick="return getQueryVariable(4)">Ver Valor 4</a>
```

Comment: Excelente @Davlio muchas Gracias Hermanoo :D

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, no se si esto te valdra. El alert lo puedes  poner tu, pero con este sistema, se evita el envio duplicado, y por lo tanto evitas que se redireccione.
Espero te ayude:

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>evitar envio duplicado</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function submit() {
                document.getElementById("submit").value = "enviando...";
               document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
                return true;
            }
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="formulario" action="#"> <!-- el asterisco le sustituimos por la URL a mandar formulario*/-->

            <input type="button" value="Enviar" onclick="this.disabled=true; this.value='enviando ...'" /> <!--añadiendo this.form.submit enviamos el formulario-->
        </form>


    </body>

    </html>
```

Un saludo

Comment: edite mi pregunta poniendo casi el mismo tu codigo yo quiero como ves la segunda imagen todo lo que tengan el idincidencia=3 quieron que me muestre un alert pero igual se sigue redireccionando.